# Change menu hover color

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, menu, fix-my-code

i want to change menu hover from green to blue color.
Please help me with the source code.

http://www.iglobez.com/about-us-page

i have used effortless joomla template

Comment: You can use a tool like **Firebug** for inspect the source code of your page in your browser, this will save you a lot of time when you try to find the correct css rule.

Answer (score 1):

In http://www.iglobez.com/templates/effortless/css/custom.css

```
.uk-navbar-nav > li:hover > a {background-color: #1abc9c;}
```

where you change the hex code to the shade of blue you want.

Comment: I have added this but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I took a look at http://www.iglobez.com/templates/effortless/css/custom.css and it looks like you did not change the color code when adding the line.  You will need to substitute the hex for the shade of blue you want with the #1abc9c.  For example, you can try #0000fff for standard bright blue to see.